# How to uninstall TeXstudio on macOS?

Tags: texstudio, installing, mac, macos

I am still new to macOS. How do I uninstall TeXstudio?
It is "only" a DMG file. Is it enough to just move it to the trash?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This is really a Mac question. If you’re running it from the DMG then close the app and eject the mounted disk image and then you can delete the DMG file. But usually you mount the DMG file and move the app to your applications folder. If that’s what you’ve done, just drag the app from there to the trash.

Comment: You may also want to remove directory `~/.config/texstuio`.